# Can I fit any model variant body kit on the same model?

Tags: body-work

Okay so we all know that you distinguish a car by its make, model and year of manufacture... But of course, there is another piece to the puzzle, aka the model variant.

I was looking to buy, say a Honda Civic. Would it be easy to fit the body kit of a Honda Civic Type-R to the aforementioned Civic?

Obviously I want to do this for aesthetic purposes, I was also considering doing the same for a Ford Focus RS body on a standard Ford Focus, or maybe at a stretch I could put the body kit of an M3 on a standard BMW 3-Series?

I feel this shouldn't be too out-of the ordinary because I know some people put the body kit of a Ferrari F430 on a Toyota MR-2.

Is it only with certain model & variant combos where this can be done or can you pretty much do this with any two cars, so long as they are the same base model and year?

thanks a bunch

Comment: This question is really broad, because it depends on the vehicle in question. When you say someone put a F430 on an MR-2, it is a specific body kit for the MR-2, so ... yes it will fit. Beyond that, it really depends on the vehicle it's coming from and going to. You cannot fit 2017 Z28 body parts on a base Camaro without major modifications (ie: more body panels than you care to swap on). It just doesn't make much sense to go that route ... and when you're done, you still have a base Camaro. Lots of models; some stuff works, some stuff won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulster2 says, it really depends on the vehicle - some will fit straight out of the box, others won't as there may be differences in the bodyshell (for example, I seem to remember the Peugeot 205 GTi shell was slightly different to the standard model, so in that case it wouldn't have fit).

I wouldn't advise doing so even if it does fit - insurance companies tend to take a dim view of it, as it marks you out as what they would consider a 'boy racer', so they'll whack your premium right up - and if you're going to be paying Type-R premiums, you might as well get a real Type-R!